# What is all the possible error output in Unix's df command

Tags: rhel, solaris, disk-usage, oracle-linux

i'm trying to make a monitoring script that do health check of the filesystem in every several seconds.

I want to monitor the "df" command, so that i can know if there is any NAS filesystem that has error(s).

To do that, i need to know what kinds of possible error output of df command.

This is an example of the error that i mean: `df: '/path/to/mounted/directory/': No such device or address`

Is there any list available of the stderr of df command?

And

Is there any possibilities that the error of a directory is not outputted on stderr but exist in the stdout?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to check the exit status of the `df` command.  The list of possible error messages is subject to change without notice -- even without upgrading the software, changing the locale can result in different messages.  The exit status, in contrast, is constant: zero for success, non-zero for failure.

The method of checking the exit status depends on how you're running `df`: in Bash, for example, it gets stored in the `$?` variable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, any kinda of error will always result in exit code >0 ?

Comment: Yes, error codes are really universal : non-zero : always = error. This can be portrayed as a counter, if there is an error then the counter is incremented

Comment: @tns2307, it's safer to check for "zero/non-zero": although exit codes in Bash are always in the range 0-255, programs are allowed to return any integer as an exit code, so it's possible to encounter negative error codes if your program is running in an unusual environment.